# Compute based on the value of time in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to compute a column based on the value of time, i'm not exactly sure what's better to use if I should use an If condition or Case?

Here are my columns

```
| Time_In               |   Time_Out            |   Val1    |   Val2    |
| 2014-07-19 04:00:04   | 2014-07-19 08:00:00   |   5       |   15      |
```

What i'm trying to do is if the time is **if the time is between '08:00:00' to '17:00:00' (business hours)  it will automatically multiply Val1 and Val2**

If the time is '18:00:00' to '23:00:00' (after business hours)

The only step I'm able to get right now is the getting the time in the timestamp cause that's what i'll be comparing

```
`SELECT date_format(STR_TO_DATE(Time_In, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%H:%i:%s') 
Output: 04:00:04

`SELECT date_format(STR_TO_DATE(Time_Out, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%H:%i:%s')
Output: 08:00:00
```

How should I construct this?

Thank You for the help

---

I tried it using the if condition first and this is working :)

```
SELECT 

IF(`Time_In` >= CAST('13:00:01' AS time) AND `Time_Out` <= CAST('15:00:00' AS time),(Val11 * Val2),'false') 


FROM table WHERE ID = '5'
```

And got the output `75` :D

Comment: Please explain, which time value should be between 04:00:00 and 10:00:00? Time_In, Time_Out, some other value?

Comment: Hmm, is it ok if the time values is just between the values `04:00:00` and `10:00:00` ? or should there be three time values?

Comment: I just don't know where this time value comes from?

Comment: I have a form and the user enters the timestamp there, if the time they entered is between 04:00:00 to 10:00:00 it will multiply columns Val1 and Val2 if its after 10:00:00 like the time is 10:00:01 it won't do anything

Comment: i changed the time to be like 08:00:00' to '17:00:00' so its like during business hours it will compute if its after it won't do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you assumed you can do that with a CASE construct.

- convert your string to a DATETIME value with STR_TO_DATE
- extract the TIME part with the [TIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function

So you could do it, here with to example values of

```
'2014-07-19 12:00:00'
'2014-07-19 18:00:00'
```

with this statement (you would need only one CASE construct of course):

```
SELECT
    CASE 
    WHEN Time(STR_TO_DATE('2014-07-19 12:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) BETWEEN '04:00:00' AND '17:00:00' 
        THEN Val1 * Val2
    ELSE NULL
    END result,

    CASE 
    WHEN Time(STR_TO_DATE('2014-07-19 18:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) BETWEEN '04:00:00' AND '17:00:00' 
        THEN Val1 * Val2
    ELSE NULL
    END result2

FROM
    example;
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a79262/18)**

Comment: Hi I just want to ask is it possible to do an update query on the if condition if the condition falls to true like `IF(Time_In >= CAST('13:00:01' AS time) AND Time_Out <= CAST('15:00:00' AS time), *UPDATE QUERY*, *INSERT QUERY*)`

Comment: @user3856951 It is possible, but only with the use of a stored routine. If you've got another question, how this could be done, please ask another question and consider to mark this as answer of this question.